# shared_ptr vs unique_ptr uses in classes and children

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

I've stared using smart pointer and trying to wrap my head around best uses for it.  I've read plenty of articles but I'm confused on which to use in the following example.  I've included a `shared_ptr` and `unique_ptr`examples to show what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
class A
    public:  
        A();
    private:
        unique_ptr<B> ptrB;

    unique_ptr<SomeObject> ptrUnique;
    shared_ptr<SomeObject> ptrShared;

    A::A()
    {
        ptrB(new B());

        ptrUnique(new SomeObject());
        ptrB->PassUnique(ptrUnique);

        ptrShared(new SomeObject());
        ptrB->PassShared(ptrShared);
    }

class B:
    public:
        void PassUnique(unique_ptr<SomeObject> &ptr_unique);
        void PassShared(weak_ptr<SomeObject> &ptr_weak);
        void DoSomething();
    private:
        unique_ptr<SomeObject> ptrUnique;
        weak_ptr<SomeObject> ptrWeak;

    B::PassUnique(unique_ptr<SomeObject> &ptr_unique)
    {
        ptrUnique = ptr_unique;
    } 

    B::PassShared(weak_ptr<SomeObject> &ptr_weak)
    {
        ptrWeak = ptr_weak;
    }

    B::DoSomething()
    {
        ptrUnique->SomeMethod();

        shared_ptr<SomeObject> ptr1 = ptrWeak.lock();
        ptr1->SomeMethod();
    }
```

SomeObject class can be any class.  A good example is a database handle that I pass from the parent class A were it was originally initiated to multiple class like B.  And from B to C if it exists.  My question is if I'm passing a unique_ptr as a reference will setting for example `ptrUnqiue = ptr_unique` in B:PassUnique create a copy which then is not correct?  Or should this be done via shared_ptr?  This understanding is what is confusing with smart pointers for me and would appreciate clarification.

Comment: You can't do `ptrUnique = ptr_unique`.. so your question seems a bit void. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/operator%3D

Comment: Thanks I wasn't quite sure of usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this is a question of lifetime. Do you need `SomeObject` to outlive `A`? Do `B` send or is being use outside of this context? You have to decide when your objects dies. If you think `SomeObject` exists only in this context, I would recommend `A` to be the owner, as it allocate the resource, and be to old a raw pointer to `SomeObject`. I would look like this:

```
class A
   public:  
     A();
   private:
     unique_ptr<B> ptrB;

     unique_ptr<SomeObject> ptrUnique;
};

A::A()
{
  ptrB(new B());

  ptrUnique(new SomeObject());
  ptrB->PassUnique(*ptrUnique);
}

class B:
  pubic:
    void PassUnique(SomeObject& obj);
    void DoSomething();
  private:
    SomeObject* ptrUnique;
};

B::PassUnique(SomeObject& obj)
{
   ptrUnique = &obj;
} 

B::DoSomething()
{
   ptrUnique->SomeMethod();
}
```

There is no such thing as

```
ptrUnique = ptr_unique;
```

If you need `SomeObject` to be used and owned outside of this structure, then go with `std::shared_ptr` like you did. There were no errors with your `std::shared_ptr` code.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on your example.  Yes SomeObject will be initiated from A and passed to B.  And maybe from B to C.  But the originator will always be A

Comment: Is it ever a good idea to use  B::PassUnique(unique_ptr<SomeObject> &ptr_unique) instead of B::PassUnique(SomeObject& obj)?

Comment: I would not recommend it. Why? Because it is not const, so your function `PassUnique` could be evil and free the pointer with the `reset` and `release` functions. But there is very little use of passing a `unique_ptr` as reference, so I would keep this thing simple and pass an `observer_ptr`, but there is no such thing yet, so the solution is to pass by raw pointer or by reference just like my example.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is basically what would be a lifetime of the pointer in the A, B and/or C. Think of it as ranges, [A...a), [B...b) and [C...c). If [B...b) is always within [A...a) and [C...c) is always within [B...b), they have like a Russian dolls hierarchy, then passing down ref-to-ptr is ok. If ranges overlap and changes wildly so you don't really control where last ptr will be destructed and object will be deleted, you'd have to go with shared_ptr.

Comment: read the question again. the OP is asking about a specific issue